# How can I add enteries on click in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f36BbdH6dCwP6Oewob0g?p=preview) as a reference. I want to create a similar one however, the change is I want to add a button and on click each entry should be added in the list. I have created this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MQFuGgzVHYqKDYxHOEdU?p=preview). However, I need to add one by one item on click. How can I achieve that? Somehow, I am doing something wrong in this code.

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
$scope.source.push($scope.counter);
$scope.counter++;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want, you need to call **$scope.source.pageSize(page);** after changing it, and then **$scope.source.refresh()** to apply this change to the source.

```
angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
  var page =1;
    $scope.source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }
        },
        pageSize: page
    });

    $scope.add= function(){
      page++;
       $scope.source.pageSize(page);
      $scope.source.refresh();
    }
});
```

[here's working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yjfS7Eqc6dRkKFaSxWIW?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You are just pushing the counter into the array, you should push the text instead.

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.source = [];
    $scope.addRow = function(text) {
      $scope.source.push(text);
    }
});
```

and in your view:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="some_text"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Add" ng-click="addRow(some_text)"/>
</div>
```

Take a look at this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/m1gkM4Yp9xzAa09NDACK?p=preview